# Simple program to find EigenValues and EignVectors for Ti 89

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to write a simple program to find the EigenValues and EigenVectors of a given Matrix, of Dimension N.

I would like to try the QR algorithm, but I don't realy know how it works.

Comment: @Moo They don't work with complex numbers.

Comment: @Moo When Eigenvalues or EigenVectors have imaginary parts.

Comment: QR factorization won't get you eigenvalues, but the [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) will